# alarmmanger sometimes works or not when the app is killed in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to notify at midnight. So I used alrammanager. the alrammanager is working well when it is in foreground or background. But the problem is occured when my app is killed. The alrammanager sometimes works or not. I don't understand this weird happening...
For example, when the notification occurs every three minutes, the app works well even if it is in the foreground or background. But when the app kiiled, the notification is occured or not even though there is no change in code. Please help me...

*MainActivity*

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val picker = findViewById(R.id.timePicker) as TimePicker
        picker.setIs24HourView(true)

        val nextNotifyTime: Calendar = GregorianCalendar()
        val nextDate: Date = nextNotifyTime.getTime()

        val currentTime: Date = nextNotifyTime.getTime()
        val HourFormat = SimpleDateFormat("kk", Locale.getDefault())
        val MinuteFormat = SimpleDateFormat("mm", Locale.getDefault())
        val pre_hour: Int = HourFormat.format(currentTime).toInt()
        val pre_minute: Int = MinuteFormat.format(currentTime).toInt()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            picker.hour = pre_hour
            picker.minute = pre_minute
        } else {
            picker.currentHour = pre_hour
            picker.currentMinute = pre_minute
        }
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val hour: Int
            val hour_24: Int
            val minute: Int
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                hour_24 = picker.hour
                minute = picker.minute
            } else {
                hour_24 = picker.currentHour
                minute = picker.currentMinute
            }
            if (hour_24 > 12) {
                hour = hour_24
            }
            else {
                hour = hour_24- 12
            }

            val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
                set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
                set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
            }

            if(calendar.after(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                //calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
            }

            diaryNotification(calendar)

        }
    }


    fun diaryNotification(calendar: Calendar) {
        val pm = this.packageManager
        val receiver = ComponentName(this, DeviceBootReceiver::class.java)
        val alarmIntent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0)
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, 60*1000, pendingIntent)
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
    }
```

*AlarmReceiver*

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
            val notificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val notificationIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            notificationIntent.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

            var notification = CustomNotification.getNotificationBuilderInstance(context)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val channelName = "channel name"
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
                val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, importance)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }


            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build())
            
        }
}
```

*DeviceBootReceiver*

```
class DeviceBootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (Objects.equals(intent.action, "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            val alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
            val pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0)
            val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val millis = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
            manager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis,
                60*1000, pendingIntent
            )
        }
    }
}
```

*Manifest*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.haii.alarmdemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".GlobalApplication"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to settings -> app -> YOUR APK NAME -> enable AUTOSTART (or something similar)

now even if your app is killed you will receive your notification

Also I suggest you to take a look at this link: [LINK](https://dontkillmyapp.com/)

Hope this "solution" can help you, cya ;)